# Can a web service client with identical signature call a different web service?

Tags: web-services, testing, jax-ws

My project has gotten into web services lately, but our QA team has a request to be able to set up a clone client and clone web service so that they can issue a request from the clone client to the real web service and from the real client to the clone service to test the real pieces individually.

The clone client to real web service part is easy, I just wrap the generated client in a main() app that picks up data to send that the test team specifies.  But the service part is confusing to me.  How can I make a dummy service that just echoes out its requests to a log without affecting the real service?  I want the real client to use the same generated client code, just point the soft-coded URL to the URL of the dummy.

If I define a new web service with identical names and signatures to the real service, can the real client hit the dummy with just a URL change?  Or is it more complicated?  Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

**Re: Making a dummy service**

This would actually be called making a "[mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)" service or a web service "[stub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_stub)". You don't even technically have to code it - you can use tools.  For example, [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) has the ability to import a WSDL and [create a mock service](http://www.soapui.org/getting-started/mock-services.html). The have some other [discussion](http://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview.html) of mock services as well - they can be used both to test the client application (or to simply develop it before the back-end resources are ready or available). To use a WSDL-based service stub you would simply change the endpoint of your client-under-test to the stub instance. SoapUI will show you (and let you configure) the stub's endpoint URL.

The trendy term for service mocking and stubbing is "[service virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_virtualization)" (not to be confused with serv*er* virtualization as in virtual machines).  Searches using this terminology will find you even more powerful (and expensive) tooling.

**Re: Just a URL Change**

Yep, for the most part. So long as the XML namespaces are the same and the WSDL is the same (minus endpoint URL) you should be fine.  Since the WSDL acts as an interface [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract), the stub MUST accept those same inputs and produce those same outputs.  How it does so, of course, is up to you.

**PS - free extra advice -** Don't *code* a dummy client. Use tools (I'll use SoapUI again as an example free tool) to make your web service testing more robust and repeatable. You can create test suites with sample SOAP requests, add [assertions](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html) on how the service should behave, and best of all - your investment in time of creating a test project can be shared across team members, cutting down time to test setup and making sure testing is thorough and repeatable. If you code a client, every tester/user of the test client will have their own way of testing, response inspection will probably be manual, and you'll notice when your best QA tester goes on vacation because regressions slip into the web service product.  Repeatable testing can nix this, and tool based automated functional testing is the bees knees.  You're already on the right path by testing the pieces individually.